# Excel | Simple Question - Text Import Wizard

Tags: excel, text, wizard

I recently used the Text Import Wizard to split some text into individual cells, for easier deletion, and where formulas use cell references.

My problem now however, is that when I pass something, it always gets split into multiple cells. I'm not sure if Excel has some sort of interal memory telling it to always treat pasted objects this way, or if I simply have to deactivate it somehow.

Comment: Anyone have any idea of how to correct this? Even in the short-term, It's really making my work tedious. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you used the text import wizard to split things previously, it will use that the next time as well. This is supposed to be for a session, but you can get it back to normal, or how you want, by running the wizard again on a file with similar characteristics to how you want. For instance open a text or csv file